# Why is the console color changing when I put it on fullscreen?

Tags: c, windows-console

Very weird bug : I'm learning C, and I tried a simple code to move a character on the screen and change its color. It works well, except when the console is on fullscreen : it fills with green (the color I use, but normally on a rectangle). How do I fix this ?

Here is the code, it's really simple :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define TX 20
#define TY 15


void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
    COORD c;

    c.X = x;
    c.Y = y;

    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), c);
}

void textcolor(int color)
{
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), color);
}



void afficher() {  //it just colors a rectangle in green

    textcolor(32);  //green background, black character
    for (int y = 0 ; y <= TY ; y++) {
        for (int x = 0 ; x <= TX ; x++) {
            gotoxy(x, y);
            putchar(' ');
        }
    }
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fin=0, res, x, y;

    srand(time(NULL));
    x = rand() % TX;
    y = rand() % TY;

    textcolor(12);
    gotoxy(x, y);
    putchar('X');

    afficher();

    while(!fin)
    {
        if (kbhit())
        {
            res = getch();
            gotoxy(x, y) ; putchar(' ');

            if (res != 224)
            {
                switch(res)
                {
                    case 72: y--; break;
                    case 77: x++; break;
                    case 80: y++; break;
                    case 75: x--; break;
                    default: fin = 1 ; break;
                }

                if(x<0)
                    x = TX;
                if(x>TX)
                    x = 0;
                if(y<0)
                    y = TY;
                if(y>TY)
                    y = 0;

                gotoxy(x, y);
                putchar('X');
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here it is, left is right after running the code, and right on fullscreen
[image]